# ofstream writing to my documents when launched remotely with shell from vba from access

Tags: c++, vba, ms-access

I have a vba scrip that launches a .exe this .exe is a program that writes to a file. These files are both in the same directory, and they're both using current directory as inputs and outputs for the read/write/launch.

The .exe writes to the current directory fine, but when I launch it through shell in vba it writes to my documents.

I genuinely have no idea why it's doing it, all I know is it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the MSAccess database that contains the VBA code is in the same directory that contains the EXE file, you can change the current directory to be that by adding the following line to the VBA code:

```
ChDir Left(CurrentDB.Name, InstrRev(CurrentDB.Name, "\") - 1)
```

That should be done somewhere prior to the `Shell` statement.

---

If the database is not in the same directory as the EXE, you might have to hardcode the path.  If, for instance, your `Shell` command is currently something like

```
Shell "C:\abc\def\xyz.exe"
```

then you could use

```
ChDir "C:\abc\def"
Shell "xyz.exe"  ' No *need* to include path information anymore
                 ' because it is now in "current" directory
```

---

The best solution though, if you have access to the code for the EXE, is to change the EXE to read/write from files which are located in the same directory as the EXE itself rather than from the "current" directory.